# How to set up ImageMagick with Liferay?

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

Following is my addition to portal-ext.properties for setting up ImageMagick with Liferay

I have installed ImageMagick in D drive as mention below :

```
imagemagick.global.search.path=D:\\ImageMagick-6.8.3-Q16
imagemagick.enabled=true
```

preview functionality:

```
dl.file.entry.preview.enabled=true
dl.file.entry.thumbnail.enabled=true
```

Set this to true to enable conversion and previewing of videos in the Document Library portlet:

```
xuggler.enabled=true
```

In Server Administration--->External servics tab, I have configured it correctly and also downloaded/install jar related to Xuggler.[image][image]

However, above settings are not working for me to generate preview functionality.

I am not even getting message dispalyed like "Generating preview require few more time, please refresh the page after some time....blah blah blah...."

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: have you installed ghostscript?

Comment: Hi, I have installed ghostscript but haven't understood use of it exactly and even after that I am not able to get through.

Comment: do you get any errors?
have you installed imagemagick and ghostscript for the same systems(e.g. 64bit each)?

Comment: Have you set XUGGLE_HOME environment variable?

Comment: As shown in attached Image, from the Liferay control panel I have installed the Jar related to Xuggler and nothing else. I am using windows 7, Can you explain how to setup rest things related to XUGGLER please.

Comment: I can see following jar files in liferay-portal-6.1.20-ee-ga2\tomcat-7.0.27\webapps\ROOT\WEB-INF\lib folder:
xuggle-xuggler-arch-i686-w64-mingw32.jar and xuggle-xuggler-noarch.jar

Answer (score 0):

Have you configured Xuggler properly? Do you get an UnsatisfiedLinkError exception?

See Xuggler's [FAQ](http://wiki.xuggle.com/Frequently_Asked_Questions#What.27s_up_with_java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError.3F) for the steps to configure your path properly

Answer (score 0):

If it shows that message "Generating preview...", seems that Liferay doesn't detect this file as a video file (the Mime Type isn't any of the values in the property: dl.file.entry.preview.video.mime.types).

I also saw this problem when uploading videos using some browsers. Try uploading using another one.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the solution was to symlink /usr/bin/convert to /usr/local/bin/convert

Whatever I did, nothing seemed to work. All configuration was pointing to /usr/bin (both control panel and portal-ext.properties). As a last resort, not really believing that it will work, I just did the symlink, as that was the default location for liferay.

And it works! All my configuration still points to /usr/bin. So... it looks like liferay just ignores all that config and only looks to default folder.

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04, imagemagick from package manager. Liferay 6.1.2 GA3.

I hope it helps someone.